# Arrange rows and columns in a single line

Tags: bash, shell

Iam using     **sar -r 1 1**     to get the output of memory consumption.
Following is the output

```
Linux XXX      SOME_DATE      ARCHITECTURE        NO. OF CPU  

02:05:38 PM kbmemfree kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit     %commit  
02:05:39 PM    125296  16209328     99.23    260300   1496748   9588744     46.71
Average:       125296  16209328     99.23    260300   1496748   9588744     46.71
```

Now I want to get rid of the first two rows and first two columns and the following command worked

```
sar -r 1 1 | sed -n 3,4p | cut -d " " -f3-
```

The output is

```
kbmemfree kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit   
   125820   16208804     99.23    260680   1499836   9588268     46.71
```

My question is, how can I arrange first column, first row= second column, second row and so on... e.g. `kbmemfree = 125820, kbmemused = 16208804,` and so on...

Comment: Thanks for the edit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe to awk and do it there:

```
 sar -r 1 1 | awk 'NR==3 {for(i=3;i<=NF;++i){a[i]=$i}} NR==4{for(i=3;i<=NF;++i){printf "%s=%s, ", a[i],$i};print '\n'}'
```

That takes the output and, if the record number is 3, captures the headers in array `a[]`. If the record number is 4, it prints out format `header=number,`